# Update property's value on another Window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

There is a property in my ViewModel whose value is changed in the DoWork method of the BackgroundWorker. When I start the application and click on the button that starts the BackgroundWorker, I see how the value of this property changes. However, when I open a new window, this property retains its default value and is not updated even though the BackgroundWorker is still running.

Her is the code in my ViewModel:

```
private string currentData;

...

public ViewModel()
    {
        ...

        // Property initialised with a default value
        currentData = "BackgroundWorker is not running";

        ...
    }

public string CurrentData
    {
        get { return this.currentData; }
        private set
        {
            if (this.currentData != value)
            {
                this.currentData = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentData");
            }
        }
    }

private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        isUpdating = true;

        ...

        this.CurrentData = "BackgroundWorker is running...";

        for (...)
        {
            ...

            if(...)
            {
                this.CurrentData = "value1";
            }

            else
            {
                this.CurrentData = "value2";

                ...
            }     
        }
    }
```

RaisePropertyChanged Method:

```
private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

XAML-code for both windows (MainWindow and newtWindow):

```
<TextBlock Margin="10" MinWidth="250" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding CurrentData}" FontSize="12" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
```

BackgroundWorker:

```
private readonly BackgroundWorker worker;

...

public ImageViewModel()
    {
        currentData = "BackgroundWorker is not running";

        this.worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        this.worker.DoWork += this.DoWork;
        this.worker.ProgressChanged += this.ProgressChanged;
        this.worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_Completeted);
        this.worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    }
```

Can you tell what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: There is a lot of ellipses (...) there. You don't see the class definition, you don't see the `RaisePropertyChanged` method and you don't see any event. Please provide code that would actually compile, otherwise it's next to impossible what's wrong.

Comment: ellipses (...) simply represent many operations that are performed. I wrote it so because the code is very long

Comment: You have instance A of class Whatevs.  You're altering the properties of instance A.  If you want two windows to display this altered version of instance A, then both windows have to have references to instance A.  How you share the instance between both windows depends on your design, who constructs the windows, and how they are constructed.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a private string reference out of your property, 
where the property can set the value and it will be saved on the stack,
something like so(this is how wpf get info from text boxes in the text property)

```
     private string _text;   //string that is used as a reference which you can plug your new new window

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return this._text;
        }
        set
        {
            this._text = value;
            if (null != PropertyChanged)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs  ("Text"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: should I use Text for the new window as I used CurrentData for MainWindow?

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid updating a property, which is bound to the UI, from a background thread. I'm not sure if this will solve your issue, but I would try to use the BackgroundWorker's [ReportProgress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/a3zbdb1t(v=vs.110).aspx) method to notify your ViewModel about changes of CurrentData. Then in the OnProgressChanged event handler you can set the CurrentData to a new String.

```
public void ReportProgress(int percentProgress, object userState)
```

You can put your String into the "userState" object.

**Edit**

something like this:

```
public ViewModel()
    {
        ...

        backgroundWorker.ReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += OnProgressChanged;

        ...
    }

private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    isUpdating = true;

    ...

    ReportProgress(0,"BackgroundWorker is running...");

    for (...)
    {
        ...

        if(...)
        {
            ReportProgress(0,"value1");
        }

        else
        {
            ReportProgress(0,"value2");

            ...
        }     
    }
}
```

and

```
private void OnProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.CurrentData = (string)e.UserState;
}
```

Comment: I have tried it but the porperty is not updated on the new Window. It retains the default value :(

Comment: How do you set the DataContext of the new window?

Comment: `<Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>`

Comment: XAML-code in new window: `<TextBlock Margin="10" MinWidth="250" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding CurrentData}" FontSize="12" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />`. It is the same code as in MainWindow

Comment: See my new answer, that might help

Answer (score 0):

Ok so from what you've said so far my understanding is as follows:

From your original question:

> However, when I open a new window, this property retains its default value and is not updated even though the BackgroundWorker is still running.

From your comment to my previous answer about setting the window's DataContext:

```
<Window.DataContext> <local:ViewModel /> </Window.DataContext>
```

When you create a new window, you also create a new instance of your ViewModel. This new instance also has its own BackgroundWorker. When you say "...even though the BackgroundWorker is still running", then this is only true for your first window, since the Backgroundworker from your new window has to be started first.

If you want the same DataContext (and thus the same BackgroundWorker) for both windows, you need to set the DataContext of your new window to the already existing instance of your ViewModel.